# Using two partial view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

In my asp.net mvc3 application i have created two partial views for two different action that is,
partialviewresult setcomment and
partialviewresult getcomment

i have created partial view using create a strongly type view and different scaffold template
for _setcomment i am using create template and for _getcomment i am using List template.

Now i want to call both _setcomment and _getcomment partial view in one view.

in my view file .cshtml

```
_setcomment - 
            @model <NAMESPACE>.<MODELNAME>
            <some code>
_getcomment - 
            @model IEnumerable<<NAMESPACE>.<MODELNAME>>
            <some code>
```

how can i call diiferent partial view in one view?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it.

If you already have the model class data in the Main view you can use like
In the main view call

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName1",model1)
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName1",model2)
```

If you do not have the model class data in the mail view then you can call the action on the controller and from there return the partial view.

```
@Html.Action("Controller","Action1")
@Html.Action("Controller","Action2")
```

In the Controller class

```
PartialResult Action1()
{
 model = new ModelClass();
 return PartialView(model);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to use the following within a single view:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControlerName"); }
@{ Html.RenderAction("ActionName2", "ControlerName2"); }
```

This would do what you are trying to achieve, however, I think there is a problem with design. What are you trying to achieve?